# How can my Java Server listens to "command.equals" code?

Tags: java, tcp, mp3

I have here a working TCP communication between my Java Server and my Android Client. My Android Client can transmit text to my server by using ports.

Now what I want is to experiment on my Java Server. What I want is when I send a "SPECIFIC" text to my server, my server will perform a task.

Example: I send "SONG_PLAY" to my server. What I want is when my server recognizes "SONG_PLAY", it will play a SPECIFIC mp3 song. Is `command.equals` applicable? or is it possible?

Hoping for your help here.

Comment: What is a "Java server"? Tomcat, websphere, derby, roll-your-own?

Comment: I program it by myself. Runs on Eclipse. Listens to port and can receive text through my android client as i'v stated above. I can show my Server code if you requested. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're asking is something like this:

```
if(command.equals("SONG_PLAY")){
    try {
        // Execute command
        String command = "rhythmbox SPECIFIC.mp3";
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

But i recommend you to use json or xml to send your request to the server.
Ex. with json:

```
{"command": "SONG_PLAY", "music": "SPECIFIC.mp3"}
```

And in the server you do something like:

```
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(s);
JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) obj;
if(((String) jobj.get("command")).equals("SONG_PLAY")){
    try {
        // Execute command
        String command = "rhythmbox " + ((String) jobj.get("music"));
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: How was it going to look like? I can post my server side code as well as my client side code? And with the xml stuff, how can I do it?

Comment: A little help here. @Arley